# dose mysql consume memory & cpu very much?

Tags: mysql, lucene, solr

currently i have a project using solr,now i want to add some feature,so i'm thinking is need add mysql to my project solution,
as i use a vps,so i must consider memory & cpu consume?
so my question is dose mysql cost memory & cpu to much ?
also i was thinking is solr can provide the same function,then i can reduce dependence
 software used in my project

Comment: Better asked at serverfault, but memory consumption (which you can limit) & CPU consumption depend entirely on what you're going to do with it. The footprint for an empty, idle MySQL instance can be quite small.

Comment: Can you please repeat the last sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory consumption of MySQL depends completely on your configuration. Giving MySQL more memory means faster queries because MySQL can cache more data in RAM.
CPU use depends on what you want to do.